# Multiple delete records from Telerik MVC Grid using checkboxes in Grid and a button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, grid

Say I have a Telerik MVC Grid, AJAX bound  and I want to put checkboxes into the Grid so that User can check them and delete multiple checked records from a Ajax.ActionLink Button which is outside  of Grid ... How to achieve this ?? I am able to put checkboxes in Grid .. but multiple deleting records when I click on a button is hard for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the checked records and put them in a List.  (See [this](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/checkboxesajax) demo from Telerik for advice on capturing the checked items.)

Then use the button to call a controller method passing in the list of records to be deleted.  Iterate through the list and delete each record.

Comment: Well I found your link useful but only problem is that after deleting a record Grid is not refreshing ... So far I have done this..<script type="text/javascript">
        function displayCheckedOrders() {var $checkedRecords = $(':checked');
       if ($checkedRecords.length < 1) {
                alert('Check a few grid rows first.');
                return;
            }

            $('#ProcessedFilesGrid').load('<%= Url.Action("DeleteMultiple", "ProcessedFiles") %>', $checkedRecords);
            debugger;
            var grid = $(this).data("tGrid");
            grid.rebind();</script>

Comment: Hmm...maybe try making your jQuery function an AJAX call an force a postback to refresh the data in the grid.  Then you may not need the grid.rebind().  Not really sure if this will work in your case, Telerik can be very picky sometimes.  But probably you will at least need to call the [GridAction] method that populates the grid after the selected records have been deleted.

Comment: I tried the same ..but grid.rebind() is not working in my case ..grid value is coming as " null"